# Stored Procedure to compare two tables and update only the data thats changed

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am new to creating stored procedures so require some support. I have two tables TableA and TableB both tables have the same columns.

what I need is to develop a stored procedure to update TableB with the information from TableA, however it should only update TableB if the data in TableA has changed. I have been pulling my hair with this. can you help !!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most products' stored procedures are far from ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008